# jQuery.fn.slideToggle vs jQuery.fn.slideDown and jQuery.fn.slideUp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

Using jQuery's slideToggle smoothly reverses an animation when you repeatedly click a toggle button without either jumping to the end or incorrectly calculating the height:

http://jsfiddle.net/kGt4Y/4/

```
$('.toggle').click(function () {
    $('.panel').stop().slideToggle();
});
```

Using jQuery's slideUp and slideDown methods together however incorrectly calculate the height when doing so:

http://jsfiddle.net/kGt4Y/3/

```
var isOpen = true;

$('.toggle').click(function () {
    if (!isOpen) {
        $('.panel').stop().slideDown();
        isOpen = true;
    }
    else {
        $('.panel').stop().slideUp();
        isOpen = false;
    } 
});
```

Does anybody know how slideToggle maintains the state and why slideDown and slideUp do not?

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent what they do? You know that jQuery is open source and you can view their code.

Comment: I get the same result on both situation

Comment: @epascarello I'm not quite sure why you think I'm trying to reinvent what they do? The animation component of jQuery is relatively complex so I've not been able to ascertain exactly how jQuery does it.

Comment: @JonathandeM. if you repeatedly click the toggle button before the animation finishes you should see that the slideDown and slideUp example get's stuck midway.

Comment: check the code https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/effects.js

Comment: @JonathandeM. If apparently you don't think I'm capable of finding the code how is it you think I'm going to be capable of reading it!?